# Functors () overloading for classes

Tags: c#

I do not think this is possible and curious if it is or why it is not:

```
class A
{

}
```

I would like to treat instances of A as functions such as

```
A a = new A();

a();
or
a(3);
etc...
```

This is to treat classes as functions for special cases when it is useful to do so. For example, I'm essentially wrapping a Func object but would love to treat an instance of such a class to act as the Func object itself. This way I don't have to have a "dummy" function to call in the class.

---

```
    public class Condition
    {
        protected Func<bool> Eval { get; set; }
        protected bool Or = false;

        protected Condition() { }
        public Condition(Func<bool> f, bool Or = false) { Eval = f; this.Or = Or; }
        protected Func<bool> GetEval(Condition c) { return c.Eval; }
        protected bool GetOr(Condition c) { return c.Or; }

    }

    public class ConditionBlock : Condition
    {
        List<Condition> Conditions;

        public ConditionBlock() { Eval = _Eval; }

        public ConditionBlock(List<Condition> Conditions) : this() { this.Conditions = Conditions; }
        public ConditionBlock(Condition[] Conditions) : this() { this.Conditions = new List<Condition>(Conditions); }
        public void Add(Condition c) { if (Conditions == null) Conditions = new List<Condition>(); Conditions.Add(c); }

        private bool _Eval()
        {
            if (Conditions == null || Conditions.Count == 0) return true;

            bool ans = !GetOr(Conditions[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < Conditions.Count; i++)
                ans = GetOr(Conditions[i]) ? ans | GetEval(Conditions[i])() : ans & GetEval(Conditions[i])();

            return ans;
        }

        public bool _()
        {
            return Eval();
        }
    }
```

To initiate the Computation I call the member *(), e.g., cblock.*(). It would look much nicer if I could call it as cblock(). Effectively a ConditionBlock is a compound function. Would be nice to be able to treat it as such. Using _() is quite ugly as is renaming it to anything else such as cblock.fire(), cblock.eval(), etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just provide an indexer (or overloaded indexers).

The only difference would be square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload the `()` operator in C#, but that's what delegates are for; they do what you describe, e.g.:

```
class AccumulateToString
{
    private int sum;
    public string ToString(int val)
    { this.sum += val; return this.sum.ToString(); }
}
var fn = new Converter<int, string>(new AccumulateToString().ToString);
Console.WriteLine(fn(2)); // <-- called like a function but is an object w/ state
```

Comment: um, I don't want a delegate. I'm wrapping a delegate and I want to treat the class as the delegate. A delegate cannot carry data with it. A class can.

Comment: A delegate *can* carry data with it, because of the `Delegate.Target` property. I extended the example in my post; take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not using Converter. Even so, Target is an object and hence not type safe.

Comment: This isn't just with Converter; it works with any delegate, and it's rather type-safe. Can you provide some sample code in C++ that you believe cannot be replicated accurately or safely in C#?

Comment: Ok, What I'm creating is a hierarchy of conditions. A condition is essentially a boolean function that takes no arguments. e.g., Func<bool>. There is some data associated with a condition which is simply how it is combined with other conditions(and or or). e.g., The hierarchy represents a compound boolean expression which is instantiated through xml. Hence the composite pattern is used. I've added the code to the original post(since I can't do it here)

Comment: I don't get it, though... instead of having a `ConditionBlock` object, why don't you just pass around a delegate for the object's `Eval` method? That way you can just call it like a function...

Comment: Again, because I need to attach data to the delegates and I need to use the composite pattern. How can I have a hierarchy without the ConditionBlock? A list of delegates is useless for a nested expression. How would you encode an arbitrary expression such as f1 & (f2 | (f3 & f4 & f5) | f6) | f7 where all the f's are delegates? They are user defined but the expression is defined in xml which must easily be translated into a way to evaluate it. There are also an arbitrary number of these expressions in the xml.

Comment: I guess the short answer is, unfortunately, that you simply can't do exactly what you're asking in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide implicit conversion to a delegate type and use the delegate type instead.

```
public class Functor
{
    private int v;

    public Functor(int v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public static implicit operator Func<int, string>(Functor f)
    {
        return (x) => (x + f.v).ToString();
    }
}
...
internal void Foo()
{
    Func<int, string> f = new Functor(42);
    var result = f(1);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what you are trying to achieve? Well, it seems that you believe that some approaches are **ugly** and you are trying to make your code **nice**. Anyway, In your case you can use an implicit operator instead if Eval method:

```
public static implicit operator bool(ConditionBlock block)
{
    return true; //make the evaluation here
}
```

the usage will be like this:

```
ConditionBlock cblock = new ConditionBlock();
// adjusting cblock
bool eval = cblock; // this is where the implicit does the magic of converting cblock to a boolean
```

Hope this helps!